# Where to get started for microsoft system management server?

Tags: deployment

I am an absolute noob as far as the Microsoft's SMS technology is concerned. Can anyone point me to some getting started links, blogs etc. I am exploring different strategies for deploying our to be built framework for a large organization.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TechNet lists some resources, including virtual labs (they're free, and useful for playing in a sandbox) here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/configmgr/bb625746.aspx.  You can also download a trial, watch some webcasts, and read the documentation here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/configmgr/default.aspx

Keep in mind that the current version of SMS is known as System Center Configuration Manager (SCCM)

Comment: Much appreciated :).